# Get a list of calls from startDate to endDate with Twilio API in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-php

I'm using the Twilio API to gather some data about our call usage. When I call the list function for the monitor alerts like this :

```js
  const endDate = "2021-04-29";
  const startDate = "2021-04-23";
  const alerts = await client.monitor.alerts.list({
    endDate,
    logLevel: "error",
    startDate,
  });
```

It lists all my calls from the start date to the end date, however when I use

```js
  const calls = await client.calls.list({
    endDate: endDate,
    startDate: startDate,
    limit: 100000,
  });
```

It times out and never returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Alerts API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/monitor-alert?code-sample=code-date-range-example&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) does indeed filter its response by `startDate` and `endDate` parameters. However, the [Calls Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) filters calls by the `startTime` and `endTime` parameters. I think your script timed out because it was trying to load 100,000 calls in pages of 50 at a time.

When you are searching between two dates, you can use `startTimeAfter` and `endTimeBefore` parameters. So I would update your script like so:

```js
  const endDate = "2021-04-29";
  const startDate = "2021-04-23";

  const calls = await client.calls.list({
    endTimeBefore: endDate,
    startTimeAfter: startDate,
    limit: 100000,
  });
```

Let me know how you go with that.